# Eclipse 4.26 : Cannot open marketplace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

I wasn't able connect to marketplace. Based on the solutions posted here in stack overflow, I followed different ways and came upon the following solution,

[image]
[image]

but now I got this error. What does this mean? How to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: What do you get when click on "Details"? What do you see when you "Show Error Log"?

Comment: Your Host value for marketplace site seems to be more than just the host name.

Comment: Details shows : This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
Connect to http://127.0.0.1:9000 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
Connection failed

Comment: One of the solution was to add this  hostname `marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api*` in proxy bypass.

Comment: You have a proxy running on your own machine that you have to go through?

Comment: Be aware that since 4.26 the Marketplace client uses HTTPS, not HTTP anymore. If a proxy is needed to connect via HTTPS to external web sites, then bypassing `marketplace.eclipse.org` does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple fix for it was I had to turn off the zscaler in my laptop and leave the network setting in eclipse ide to active provider as direct.